# How to use string resources without error?

Tags: android, string

I got this error when trying to replace all hardcoded strings with equivalents of it in strings.xml. Apparently people had this error when trying to use integers but all my strings are strings in this case.

The error:

```
2021-03-25 19:48:25.233 676-676/com.asdf.asdf E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.asdf.asdf, PID: 676
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0f0002
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:360)
    at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:97)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:453)
    at com.emirhalici.myenglishdictionary.AddWordAdapter$eViewHolder$1.onClick(AddWordAdapter.java:44)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6878)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
```

strings.xml file:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">MyEnglishDictionary</string>
<string name="Home">Home</string>
<string name="Quiz">Quiz</string>
<string name="AddWord">Add Word</string>
<string name="ToastErrorResponse">Error while getting response.</string>
<string name="TextViewAddHint">Enter the word you\'re looking for.</string>
<string name="btn_add_manually">Add Manually</string>
<string name="btn_search_word">Search Word</string>
<string name="No">No</string>
<string name="Yes">Yes</string>
<string name="AddWordAlertDialogTitle">Are you sure?</string>
<string name="AddWordSuccess">Word added to database successfully.</string>
<string name="AddWordAlertDialogMessage">The word %1$s will be added to dictionary.</string>
```

related java code:

```
        public eViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_type = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_type);
        tv_word = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_word);
        tv_definition = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_definition);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MaterialAlertDialogBuilder dialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context);
                String alertTitle = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.AddWordAlertDialogTitle);
                dialogBuilder.setTitle(alertTitle);

                String word = mWordList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getWord();
                String alertMessage = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.AddWordAlertDialogMessage, word);
                dialogBuilder.setMessage(alertMessage);

                dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.Yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                        databaseHelper.addOne(mWordList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                        Toast.makeText(context, Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.AddWordSuccess), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.No), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });

                dialogBuilder.show();

            }
        });
    }
```

AddWordAdapter.java:44 is the line

```
String alertTitle = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.AddWordAlertDialogTitle);
```

**EDIT:** Problem occured because I was using *Resources.getSystem().getString()* instead of *context.getResources().getString()*. Problem is now solved. Thank you micheal. I can't seem to be able to mark this post as solved I'm new here.

Comment: Why are you calling `Resources.getSystem()`?  Did you mean to simply call `getResources()` (which is a method available from within any `Context`, e.g. an `Activity`).

Comment: @Michael I am doing operations on a java class and getResources() simply isn't recognized here. The class AddWordAdapter.java is an adapter for recyclerview cards that i use to list words. Inside the class, inside the itemView.setOnClickListener I open call dialog builder and that's when I use strings. App worked until I changed hardcoded strings to these. What is the alternative to getResources? I thought Resources.getSystem() would work as it was suggested.

Comment: Well, you seem to have a `context` variable, so call `context.getResources()` I guess. `Resources.getSystem()` is, as [the documentation states](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getSystem()), for getting _"a global shared Resources object that provides access to only system resources (**no application resources**)"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Micheal pointed out, I used Resources.getSystem() to get strings from resources. Instead I should have used a context to call getResources(). A simple fix should look like this.

```
String alertMessage = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.AddWordAlertDialogMessage, word); // error
String alertMessage = context.getResources().getString(R.string.AddWordAlertDialogMessage, word);
```